# How to sort data according to the time picked by date picker Using Realm in Swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, database, sorting, realm

I have one date picker. It chooses the starting time and is displayed in a text field as a string. I have a table view in which each cell would show that textfield. And also I have an add button which then saves the text field's string in the realm database. Realm is used t load the tavleView. Now I want to sort the data in the realm so that it displays the cells according to the starting time that each cell has.

```
class NewActivityTableViewController: UITableViewController {
   @IBOutlet weak var startingTimeTxt: UITextField!
   
   let datePickerTime = UIDatePicker()
   let realm = try! Realm()
   
   override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   startingTimeTxt.delegate = self
   
   datePickerTime.datePickerMode = .time
  }
```

Then I connected my textView with the date picker and on pressing a toolbar done button, it got displayed as a string.

```
@objc func donePressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    //formatter
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .none
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    
    startingTimeTxt?.text = formatter.string(from: datePickerTime.date)
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    
}
```

Then on pressing the add button , all of the data will get stored to the realm

```
@IBAction func AddButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    
    let cell = ScheduleCellDetails()
    
    cell.startingTime = startingTimeTxt.text ?? ""
    
    saveSchedule(cell: cell)
}

 func saveSchedule(cell: ScheduleCellDetails) {
    do {
        try realm.write {
            realm.add(cell)
        }
    } catch {
        print("Error saving category \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

My realm data class

```
class ScheduleCellDetails: Object {

@objc dynamic var startingTime: String = ""
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just sort the array of `[ScheduleCellDetails] ` you're feeding to your tableview? `[ScheduleCellDetails].sorted{$0.startTime < $1.startTime()}`
(You'd need to format them to date instead of string)

Comment: @shayegh While your answer makes sense (there's a typo though), it's not generally a good solution for Realm as doing that kind of sort will disconnect the objects from Realm so they will no longer be live updating. Additionally, Realm objects are lazily loaded so thousands of objects have a minimal memory impact. With that code, ALL of the data is loaded into memory.

Comment: OP; you've asked a question but the included code has almost nothing to do with the actual question. We don't know what `saveSchedule` does, why you're storing a date/time object as a String (?) or what that string contains (it's format). Also, where is your sorting code and how are you sorting by starting *and* ending. In other words, what's the goal there? The start time has an associated end time so if you sort by one, the other would (may be) unsorted. Can you include your code and update the question?

Comment: @Jay I have updated the question , I just have to deal with the starting time now and I have added the saveSchedule method code. It just saved the entered data into the realm. As I said in the question , I needed my textField to show the chosen time by the date picker that is why I converted the time into a string by using a formatter and stored it in the realm as a string. String just contains time in the following format: 10:00 PM etc. I didn't add the sorting code because that is what I didn't understand how to do.

Comment: @Jay I was thinking to sort my data, I would create another variable in my realm data class called sortingTime: Date(), and it will store the date (as Date() object ) picked by the datePicker and then just before loading my tableview, I will sort the results array that I get from my realm according to this sortingTime. Something like this :  scheduleCell = realm.objects(ScheduleCellDetails.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "sortingTime")

Comment: The problem with storing times as a string is how it will be sorted. Chronologically, 1:00AM, 2:00AM...10:00AM,11:00AM is the correct sequence. However, as strings, they will be sorted like this 1:00AM, 10:00AM, 11:00AM, 2:00AM etc. I would suggest either storing them as either actual Date objects or as integers in a hhmm format like this 0100, 0200...1000, 1100...1300 etc. That will keep the sorting correct. Once we know how you want to do that, the sorting part will be easy.

Comment: @Jay, I think storing them as actual Date objects will be a better option for me. Then we can sort the results array that we receive from the realm based on these actual Date objects.